# MySQL query to return most proposed books in a month

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table named "proposals":

- proposal_id
- proposal_user (int
- proposal_book (int)
- proposal_date (Y-m-d)

Users are going to propose books each month so there will be like 50-100 books per month. I would like to know if there's a way of writing a query that can return the most proposed books for a given month.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  proposal_book, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM    proposals
WHERE   proposal_date >= $first_day_of_month
        AND proposal_date < $first_day_of_month + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY
        proposal_book
ORDER BY
        cnt DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM proposals GROUP BY proposal_book ORDER BY COUNT(proposal_id) DESC
```